# Delete rows that already appear in table

Tags: sql, pdo, sql-delete

I've having some SQL issues today and duplicated a table's records several times trying to revert to a backup. Table is currently like the below:

```
id user col1 col2 col3 ...
1   3    0     9    3  ...
2   4    1     2    1  ...
3   2    1     9    2  ...
...
1   3    0     9    3  ...
2   4    1     2    1  ...
3   2    1     9    2  ...
...
...
```

Each record appears five times. I only want one each. I've tried manually deleting a bunch but there's 3,000+ when there should only be 600. Not all records appear five times (some four times) since I deleted a bunch, but I'd rather do it in one fell swoop. To note is that if `id` matches between two rows, all of the subsequent columns will also match, so just deleting rows of duplicate `id` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily delete duplicates just by grouping them up.

like:

```
Select 
id,user,col1,col2,.... 
from the Table_name
group by 
id,user,col1,col2,....
```

This would remove duplicates at the level of all columns and hence solves your problem

Comment: Why GROUP BY when no aggregate functions are involved? Simply do SELECT DISTINCT instead...

Comment: Computationally GROUP BY is more efficient than using a DISTINCT function. Though they provide same results, GROUP BY works faster.

Comment: Perhaps true for some dbms product(s), but probably not for the majority of them. (And no dbms specified in the question...)

Comment: True that. So then, DISTINCT or GROUP BY, either can be used.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to delete the duplicate records is by using the CTE and `ROW_NUMBER()` over Partition by Column list. below is the syntax to delete the duplicate rows.

```
WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT [col1], [col2], [col3], [col4], [col5], [col6], [col7],
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1)
   FROM dbo.Table1
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Checkout [How to Delete Duplicate Rows in sql](http://code.askmein.com/how-to-delete-duplicate-rows-in-sql/) with an example and more details on how to use the query.